# Paypal/Google checkout with Drupal

Tags: drupal, paypal, shopping-cart

Is there a simple way in implement Paypal/Google cart (cart not button) with my Drupal website with out installing big over complicated modules such as ubercart and ecommerce? Just want to click add to chart and then hit checkout which takes me to Paypal/Google checkout to do the rest.

UPDATE: I should add that i'm running Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modules like [Google Checkout](http://drupal.org/project/google_checkout) or [Simple Paypal Framework](http://drupal.org/project/simple_paypal)? Paypal has many modules advertised as simple, try to look on [Drupal Modules](http://drupalmodules.com/search/node/paypal). Good luck.